# How to test navigation from DialogFragment to another DialogFragment?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, testing, android-dialogfragment

I'm using the Navigation component for my two DialogFragments and when I press a button on the first DialogFragment it is dismissed and then the second one is shown. I need to test that clicking this button will take me to the second dialog. I have a simple home fragment that is overlayed by the first DialogFragment at the start of the app. The following code is from the first DialogFragment.

```
 /**
 * Redirects users to another dialog after pressing button
 */
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.firstDialogFragment) {
            findNavController().navigateUp()
            val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToSecondDialogFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
}
```

This next bit of code comes from the developer's guide and only checks for the behavior of dismissing a DialogFragment back to the previous Fragment.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTestSuite {
    @Test fun testDismissDialogFragment() {
        // Assumes that "MyDialogFragment" extends the DialogFragment class.
        with(launchFragment<MyDialogFragment>()) {
            onFragment { fragment ->
                assertThat(fragment.dialog).isNotNull()
                assertThat(fragment.requireDialog().isShowing).isTrue()
                fragment.dismiss()
                fragment.requireFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()
                assertThat(fragment.dialog).isNull()
            }

            // Assumes that the dialog had a button
            // containing the text "Cancel".
            onView(withText("Cancel")).check(doesNotExist())
        }
    }
}
```

I need some way to test the behavior of a DialogFragment's button and see that it dismisses itself **and** starts the second DialogFragment.

When I test for the button being clicked, the first DialogFragment is correctly dismissed, but the second DialogFragment is not launched. I've used both Espresso and UiAutomator and the click does occur, but reading the code snippet's explanation for testing DialogFragments it says,

"Even though dialogs are instances of graphical fragments, you use the launchFragment() method so that the dialog's elements are populated in the dialog itself, rather than in the activity that launches the dialog".

Is the reason that I am unable to check if the second DialogFragment exists or not, because it is an instance of a graphical fragment and my click listener for the button on the first DialogFragment cannot implement launchFragment() for the second DialogFragment?

Comment: narrate the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: I used the example test code except instead of fragment.dismiss(), I do a click with UiAutomator that is supposed to take me to the next DialogFragment. The click is supposed to dismiss the first DialogFragment and then launch the second DialogFragment. When normally run the app works fine, but my problem occurs in that the second DialogFragment is not launched in the tests so any asserts to check if the second DialogFragment is launched fails.